# Shift left followed by round for performing: y=x+cz in hardware

Tags: adder, multiplier, arithmetic-division

I wan't to implement a simple arithmetic, given the following (say 8 bits) integers x,y,z
$$y = x + c z$$
where 'c' is a fraction of a power of 2: 2^-1, 2^-2, 2^-3,...

I was adviced to perform the following:

1) shift left x by the power of c (if c=2^-3, then shift left 3 times)

2) add z

3) shift right the result c times again to obtain the final answer

Why is it better than simply performing shift right to z according to c and then adding x?

Thanks

Comment: Simulate both in parallel. For 8 bits each you can exhaustively test; it's just 2 loops in your testbench. If you can find a case that delivers different results you have your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you shift z right first you will immediately discard the lower bits of z. That information is gone forever.

If you first shift x left and keep all of its bits, then add z, you will have preserved as much information as you can. Rounding back to 8 bits at this point will give you the most accurate answer.

In general, when using integer arithmetic you want to defer division as long as you can. Do all of the multiplications and addition first, then have one final step where you divide with rounding.

Comment: I understand the motivation you explaind. Is there a simple example where it would hurt to shift simply shift right z? I suspect that in my simple case, the result will always be the same

Comment: Suppose x=0001 1111, z=0000 0111, and c=2^-3. If you shift z right three places you get 0000 0000, so nothing important happens...the result is 00011111. Try shifting x left three places while keeping all of the bits and you get 000 1111 1000. Add z and you get 000 1111 1111. Now **round** and divide...add 100 before you shift right. The result is 00100000.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using division in HDL (hardware description language) turns to be very inneficient and you also may lose accuracy. Furthermore, "true division" does not exist in HDL, and it is usually accomplished with different algorithms. Hence, it is usually advisable to convert all decimal numbers to integers before initiating you mathematical operations.
Considering your case, even though you are dealing with integers, `c` is a fraction and as such, it would lead to some division operation.